# Why are consequences usually associated with something negative?

Tags: meaning

Consequence often has a negative tone. For example, we are more likely to say, "Bob did not study, as a consequence he failed his test." But for the opposite we usually say, "Bob studied, therefore he passed his exam." Consequence actually just means as a result of so you could actually say, "Bob studied and as a consequence, he passed." Instead we usually associate consequence with something negative instead of positive, what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Because the word, when spoken to a child or underling, sounds so imposing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an unsupported supposition that *consequence* is used more negatively than positively.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite normal to speak of *positive* consequences, although (see below) use of the term *without context or detail* can seem threatening.  *With* context, the word itself has been used in many fields with associations of appropriate understanding or planning, resulting in positive outcomes.

The term itself seems not to be inherently loaded:  in these uses it carries no stigma.  My research today (see below) suggests that ‘consequences’ can imply rewards, reprisals or simply information, fairly equally.

A related possibility is that the term ‘as a consequence’ might often be observed in the wild in cases where someone is trying to avoid or explain a failure, perhaps with shorthand such as ‘dire consequences’ or ‘face the consequences’.  You might be thinking of the open-ended declaration, ‘There will be consequences,’ which generally operates as a warning or even a threat.  This does not make the base concept negative, any more than ‘face the music’.

There are still plenty of examples of ‘consequences’ referring to analytical concepts or positive outputs of particular actions.  In relation to the Question, the important point seems to be the *absence* of any problematic sense *at all* of working against a *conventionally* negative association.  The term appears to be essentially neutral.

The site yourdictionary.com offers (at my count) [101 user examples](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/consequence#Lr6rYFZidyAgDscF.97) of the word ‘consequence’ in normal use.  This seems to be a reasonable corpus, at least for straw poll purposes, with no inbuilt motivation to skew selection.  I went through them to determine whether these examples might imply in each case that the *consequence*[*s*] should be *deplored or feared*, *welcomed or even celebrated*, or simply *noted analytically*.

Disregarding eight examples of the slightly different usage ‘of [any/no] consequence’ (although in these expressions ‘consequence’ operates *consistently* as a *desirable* quality), the remaining 93 break down as follows:

> negative association:  32  (34%)
>
> neutral association:  33  (35%)
>
> positive association:  28  (30%)

To be sure, in this list *positive* usages come out *slightly* lower than the other two categories (although including ‘*of* consequence’ would make positives the clear ‘winner’).

If we include the examples of ‘of [any/no] consequence’, the figures change but still make essentially the same point:

> negative association:  32  (32%)
>
> neutral association:  33  (33%)
>
> positive association:  36  (35%)

Statistically speaking, either way, the interesting thing seems to be that usage is pretty much evenly-spread.  Without embarking on a major textual analysis across a multitude of publications, I can’t think of a more innocently democratic accumulation of instances.

There are many more specialised examples.  I think that the important thing here is not to try to *position* the word positively *or* negatively, but to note that it appears to carry no particular association independent of context.  No-one seems to be scared to use it.

An article on parenting (on [boystown.org](http://www.boystown.org/parenting/article/positive-consequences-mean-keep-up-the-good-work?/article/positive-consequences-mean-keep-up-the-good-work)) claims that ‘**Positive consequences** (or rewards) are things your child likes and enjoys.’

The professional site internetretailer includes [an article about e-commerce](http://www.internetretailer.com/2015/10/01/happy-consequences) entitled simply ‘**Happy Consequences**’.

Hiper-com.com [describes Global Data Synchronisation](http://www.hiper-com.com/en/blog/2013/11/18/gdsn-boring-subject-exciting-consequences/#.VwjYbpwrKt8) as a ‘boring subject with **exciting consequences**’, an instance where consequences are automatically *so positive* as to make up for initial struggle.

A quick search yields [an article in the professional journal Industrial and Commercial Training](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/ICT-05-2013-0034?journalCode=ict) (Vol 47 #1, 2015), entitled ‘Employee empowerment: factors affecting the **consequent success or failure** (Part II)’, showing that  ‘consequences’ need not imply *inherent* positive or negative value.

The book *Transformative classroom Management* (Shindler, 2009) ‘**Creating Effective Consequences** Within the Social Contract’:

> Developing **logical and related consequences** is crucial to achieving a
>   social contgract that feels **democratic** and is built on **promoting responsibility**.
>
> [...]
>
> The **most successful consequences** are those that are logical and
>   related, built in proactively, reflect the buy-in and ownership of the
>   students, and **contribute to long-term growth** and behaviour change.

[Thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consequent) points to a range of examples, including...

Nathaniel Hawthorne, *[The House of Seven Gables](http://hawthorne.thefreelibrary.com/House-Of-Seven-Gables/1-13)*:

> He then renewed the conversation, and made great pecuniary offers to
>   the carpenter, in case the latter should give information leading to
>   the discovery of the lost document, and the **consequent success** of the
>   Eastern claim.

Mark Twain, *[A Tramp Abroad](http://twain.thefreelibrary.com/Tramp-Abroad/0-49)*:

> But one is calm before St. Mark’s, one is calm in the cellar; for its
>   details are masterfully ugly, no misplaced and impertinent beauties
>   are intruded anywhere; and the **consequent result is a grand harmonious
>   whole**.

Comment: I'm only guessing at the reason for the downvote (it isn't mine) – while it's true that we can speak of positive consequences, it seems far easier to find instances where the word is being used in a negative or neutral sense. Had the question said "always" (instead of "usually" and "often"), this might be more deserving of an upvote. But a handful of counterexamples doesn't negate the premise of the question, which is left unaddressed.

Comment: @J.R. I took your hypothesis to heart and embarked on an impossible survey towards the impossibly unprovable _lack_ of significant skew. I did better than I had been willing to expect.

The word _consequence[s]_ seems blameless. The interesting thing (in a different Question) might turn out to be its persisting neutrality despite its part in some negative expressions.

I am new-ish here, so unexplained random downvotes are still sort-of-exciting, but I do wish people would suggest _why_ they disapprove of things. If I had merely said 'I think it's a fish,' it would be obvious. Oh, well.

Comment: See the thing is, for positive consequences, you added a positive word in front of consequence for a lot of them. Though in your examples there were two that did not need a positive word in front of consequence and consequence did not have a negative connotation. Happy, exciting, successful consequences all have a positive word in front of consequence. While you can still add a negative word in front of consequence, most of the time we don't and I think it's because of the phrase "face the consequences," as you have pointed out.

Comment: In my individual examples, that happens, yes:  I was explicitly making a point.  I don't think that the examples from the yourdictionary list, however, generally include qualifiers that would significantly shunt interpretation.  As far as I can tell, the sense seems to be rather evenly distributed, and not implicitly loaded.

Comment: [@user1470901 I responded to your comment, but forgot to tag you]

Answer (score 0):

The word has a negative prefix in "con" and then the word sequence which to me should mean that consequence is a negative effect of an action or situation.

Comment: The "con" in "consequence" is not a negative prefix; "consequence" comes from the Latin _consequentia_, which comes from the verb _consequi_ (to follow along), which comes from _cum_ (with) + _sequi_ (to follow).

Sources: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consequence, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consequentia#Latin, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consequent#etymology